# Django validation of generic relation from a GenericInlineModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to validate a generic relation object saved from a GenericInlineModelAdmin form.

When the object is created `object_id` and `content_type` are set to `None`, and I cannot access it's related object, but when the object is updated they are properly set.

Here is the sample code:

In `models.py`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    body = models.TextField()

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def clean(self, exclude=None):
        pass
```

In `admin.py`:

```
class InlineTags(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = TaggedItem

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineTags]

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

If you add a tag, in `TaggedItem.clean()` method `self.object_id` and `self.content_type` are set to `None`. If the tag is being edited they are properly set.

I have tried this on both django 1.4.x and 1.5.x.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is an unresolved bug in Django (issue [#19255](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19255)).

I have yet to test it, but since you are saving the tags in the admin you may be able to work around this issue by adding a custom ModelForm like so:

```
class InlineTagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        """ Validate object_id & content_type fields """
        assert self.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        assert self.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        return self.cleaned_data


class InlineTags(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = TaggedItem
    form = InlineTagsForm
```